My comment wasn't posted when voting to close as "Other" as the final vote. Is this a bug?
This might be a duplicate of No comment posted when question is closed as off-topic because ... > other
Reference question: Ballistic Coefficients in a Zero G and Perfect Vacuum
I was the final close vote and my close vote of Off-Topic Because...->Other was unique (the other VTCs were for 1X missing details, 1X needs focus and 2X duplicate).
The comment I wrote as part of the close vote did not get posted to the question comment chain. I have not yet replicated the message in a new comment.
I'm loathe to try and replicate the bug as that means arbitrarily closing one or more questions. However, if required, let me know and I'll go find some 4-vote examples, beg for forgiveness, and test the bug.

@W.O. It would be interesting to know if this is a repeatable behavior. Ideally, we want four non/Off-Topic->Other votes with a final Off-Topic->Other vote to see if the comment appears. How would you like to proceed?

Wish we could see who's online on W/B, I'd pick some old posts of curators/mods and ping them to coordinate here. Could comment that anyone who'll be free for the next twenty minutes might join. Random selection I guess, mass mailing as it were. Assuming a hit rate of...?

If you want, you could try, and I could re-open any that I don't think should be closed.  Ping me in https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17213/the-factory-floor with the questions you close.

@W.O. We're going to try the bug test with this question. Remember that we're looking for four non-off-topic->other votes so that I can cast the final vote as I did for the sake of this post. Thanks for helping!

Hi @JBH - was pinged by Escaped dental patient.  Cast a close vote on the question listed as requiring more details.  Let me know if that's not what's wanted and I'll retract.

@KerrAvon2055 Just what I needed. Thanks!

@JBH How's the test going?

@MontyWild EDP can't remember how he closed the question and he wasn't expected to close it at all. I believe that attempt was corrupted and this question remains unverified one way or the other.

I wonder if it's because the final result was duplicate closure, thus the closure comment was also cleaned-up?

I was able to reproduce it here - it might need some further research whether it's related to duplicate closure as @MetaAndrewT. educatedly guesses.

I just realized you might be able to ask a moderator and check if there's a deleted comment or no comment posted at all.

@MetaAndrewT. Hopefully Glorfindel did that, however.... Voting to close as a duplicate can (can...) cause a comment to be posted. Possibly one for each new "duplicate" that's voted. But it also happens only once with the first duplicate vote per-reference question. That means there's an if-then in the code asking if the comment's been posted before... and that if-then might be getting in the way of the Off-Topic->Other posting action. In that case, there wouldn't be anything to find.
